# How to show custom failure messages in ScalaTest?

Tags: scala, scalatest, matcher

Does anyone know how to show a custom failure message in ScalaTest?

For example:

```
NumberOfElements() should equal (5)
```

Shows the following message when it fails:

> 10 did not equal 5

But i want more descriptive message like:

> NumberOfElements should be 5.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You're the first to ask for such a feature. One way to achieve this is with withClue. Something like:

```
withClue("NumberOfElements: ") { NumberOfElements() should be (5) }
```

That should get you this error message:

NumberOfElements: 10 was not equal to 5

If you want to control the message completely you can write a custom matcher. Or you could use an assertion, like this:

```
assert(NumberOfElements() == 5, "NumberOfElements should be 5")
```

Can you elaborate on what your use case is? Why is it that 10 did not equal 5 is not up to snuff, and how often have you had this need?

Here's the kind of thing you're requesting:

```
scala> import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers._
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers._

scala> withClue ("Hi:") { 1 + 1 should equal (3) }
org.scalatest.TestFailedException: Hi: 2 did not equal 3
at org.scalatest.matchers.Matchers$class.newTestFailedException(Matchers.scala:150)
at org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers$.newTestFailedException(ShouldMatchers.scala:2331)


scala> class AssertionHolder(f: => Any) {
     |   def withMessage(s: String) {
     |     withClue(s) { f }
     |   }
     | }
defined class AssertionHolder

scala> implicit def convertAssertion(f: => Any) = new AssertionHolder(f)
convertAssertion: (f: => Any)AssertionHolder

scala> { 1 + 1 should equal (3) } withMessage ("Ho:")
org.scalatest.TestFailedException: Ho: 2 did not equal 3
at org.scalatest.matchers.Matchers$class.newTestFailedException(Matchers.scala:150)
at org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers$.newTestFailedException(ShouldMatchers.scala:2331)
```

So this way you can write:

```
{ NumberOfElements() should be (5) } withMessage ("NumberOfElements:")
```

Comment: There are situations where i had to put more than one assertion in a it() test and there are more than one integer comparision. It is not clear by looking at the logs which assertion has failed.

Comment: But the withClue way of specifying it is not readable. Isnt there a way of specifying the message at the end?

Comment: At the end isn't doable with the matcher's DSL, but you can write a method that puts the withClue params in the opposite order. I'll add an example to the answer.

Answer (score 13):

New way since 2011: `Matchers` and `AppendedClue`<sup>1</sup> traits. Also, for collection sizes, there are some default messages.

```
import org.scalatest.{AppendedClues, Matchers, WordSpec}

class SomeTest extends WordSpec with Matchers with AppendedClues {

  "Clues" should {
    "not be appended" when {
      "assertions pass" in {
        "hi" should equal ("hi") withClue "Greetings scala tester!"
      }
    }
    "be appended" when {
      "assertions fail"  in {
        1 + 1 should equal (3) withClue ", not even for large values of 1!"
      }
    }
    "not be needed" when {
      "looking at collection sizes" in {
        val list = List(1, 2, 3)
        list should have size 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
SomeTest:
Clues
  should not be appended
  - when assertions pass
  should be appended
  - when assertions fail *** FAILED ***
    2 did not equal 3, not even for large values of 1! (SomeTest.scala:15)
  should not be needed
  - when looking at collection sizes *** FAILED ***
    List(1, 2, 3) had size 3 instead of expected size 5 (SomeTest.scala:21)
```

Note that the `List` size message isn't great for lists with long `.toString` output.

See the [scaladoc](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.AppendedClues) for more information.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm guessing the `AppendedClues` trait was inspired by this question, Bill Venners of the accepted answer is the author of this trait.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `withClue` without importing anything or adding it to the test class:

```
withClue(s"Expecting distinct elements: ${elements.toList}") { elements.length shouldBe 3 }
```

This is imported from `Assertions` class: `org.scalatest.Assertions#withClue`

Comment: What does this add on top of the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Few things that none of the existing answers mention.

1. The position of `withClue` determines where the custom message goes. If written as `withClue(<message>) { <assertion> }`, the `message` is prepended, if written as `{ <assertion> } withClue(<message>)`, the `message` is appended.
2. In order to use `withClue` as an infix operator, `org.scalatest.AppendedClues` must be mixed in, or `org.scalatest.AppendedClues.convertToClueful` imported.
3. Scala 3 doesn't allow methods with entirely alphabetic names to be used as infix if not defined with the `infix` keyword. In order to get around this, enclose `withClue` in backticks, like so: `{ <assertion> }` `withClue` `(<message>)`